# Errors in IE 9 after upgrading to Domino 9.01 Server

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I am asking on behalf of our administrator.  Last night the administrator upgraded our production server from 8.5 to 9.01.  Today a handful of people using IE 9 are having issues with clientside javascript errors in one application.  This problem does not affect all machines, and in fact the application works fine for me when I try it using IE9.  In the machines that it fails, it fails every time, in the machines that it works, it works every time.  It works for the majority of people.  The application works fine in FF and Chrome (insert sarcasm here)

The problems seems to be isolated to one application, an Xpages application that I wrote.  It has been deployed for over 8 months and has been very stable until today.  I do not believe there is an application problem but here are the errors that it gives

> Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined

This error comes from one of the files generated by the domino server.  The file is:

> `https://my_company/my_app.nsf/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.en-us/@Im.js`

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: Are you using OneUI theme? If so which one.

Comment: Simon, theme is set to "Server Default"

Comment: This may be a naive question, but:  Is the Javascript being generated by Notes 9 the same as you were seeing in Notes 8.5?  If it's not, and if it's wrong, then you'd need to file an SPR with Notes.

Comment: Eric, I don't think there is any difference in the javascript between the two versions, although we don't have a 8.5 server anymore to compare.  I thinking it is somethings else.

Comment: Try clearing the browser cache on the failing machines and try again

Comment: Per, just walked over there, and he already tried that and it didn't help.

Comment: Have you thought about the version of DOJO? I you can drop the version Dojo back to the previous version on an app basis for testing. Also were you using 8.5 or 8.5.x?

Comment: Facing similar issues with 9.0.1 when using the "runtime optimized Js and CSS" in my application. Disable that and try again.

Comment: @Patrick, good point I hadn't thought of that.  The previous dojo version was the default (blank).  If that was the issue though I would expect it to fail for everyone. The application was always 8.5.3 from the start.

Comment: @Oliver, that checkbox it set.  I will try disabling that and let you know what happens.

Comment: @Oliver, I just checked with the administrator and that did fix the issue.  Thankfully this is a fairly low volume app so the performance hit should be minimal.  If you would, please go ahead and answer the question, and I will accept the answer, thanks!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Steve said in the comments: disable the "runtime optimized JS and CSS" setting as this seems to be an 9.0.1 issue. Facing similiar issues with other frameworks such as Bootstrap 3 where Glyphicons were not rendered properly when this option is activated.

Comment: Just for fun, I enabled it again, and it fails again.  It is definitely the issue.  This could also be a bug in the way the files are optimized.  Thank you!!

Comment: An alternative to the XPages "runtime optimized" could be mod_pagespeed ... if you run Domino behind Apache/IHS

Comment: We're investigating this issue

Comment: @Paul Hannan, the problems seems to occurr only when usig resources in WebContent folder. In my case I can use optimized setting with bootstrap4xpages plugin (as I am using BS here) but when implementing my own Bootstrap stuff it fails. This maybe interesting when investigating.

Answer (score 1):

background-position-x is not present in IE9, background-position-y is available. Can it be caused by home-made js animation of css? Have to be manipulated with the single background-position css property instead.